# Find between 2 strings but Last Index should be first found C#

Tags: c#, xml, string

Hello guys Im looking for solution to find text in string between 2 phrases, but for example not last one in string but first found.
where:

```
mainString = <Message>1</Message><Message>2</Message><Messages>3</Message>
leftBracket = "<Message>"
rightBracket = "</Message>"
```

because right now it return me `1<Message><Message>2<Message><Message>3`
but I want to return value 1

```
 private string between2strings(string mainString, string leftBracket, string rightBracket)
        {
            int pFrom = mainString.IndexOf(leftBracket) + leftBracket.Length;
            int pTo = mainString.LastIndexOf(rightBracket);

            string result = mainString.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);

            return result;
        }
```

I want to show all code after remove my contact info, or maybe I should change the method of reading data:

Here full xml in string Im trying to find data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
    <Count>2</Count>
    <Messages>
        <Message>
            <Smstat>0</Smstat>
            <Index>20001</Index>
            <Phone>+4857782</Phone>
            <Content>Test4</Content>
            <Date>2021-12-11 14:24:23</Date>
            <Sca>+4879096</Sca>
            <SaveType>4</SaveType>
            <Priority>0</Priority>
            <SmsType>1</SmsType>
        </Message>
        <Message>
            <Smstat>0</Smstat>
            <Index>20000</Index>
            <Phone>+4857782</Phone>
            <Content>Test3</Content>
            <Date>2021-12-11 14:02:48</Date>
            <Sca>+4879096</Sca>
            <SaveType>4</SaveType>
            <Priority>0</Priority>
            <SmsType>1</SmsType>
        </Message>
    </Messages>
</response>
```

Comment: _Messages != Message_

Comment: In any case, if you want the first occurence then do not use LastIndexOf, but just IndexOf to search for right bracket

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Comment: If you are parsing XML please consider using an XML parser, you might find this useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/find-child-element

Comment: This question turned out to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/172321).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you parse the XML document using the `XmlDocument` object and navigate its content using an XPath expression. Here is an example

```cs
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.Load("Test.xml");
            XmlNodeList xmlNodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("/response/Messages/Message");
            foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodeList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(xmlNode.InnerXml);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Fabio

Answer (score 0):

**Old answer before the whole input string was published**

Use [Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_):

```cs
var mainString = "<Messages>1</Message><Messages>2</Message><Messages>3</Message>";
string[] parts = mainString.Split(new [] { "<Messages>", "</Messages>" }, 
                                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This yields the array: `{ "1", "2", "3" }` and makes it easy to pick the required entry:

```cs
string result = parts[0];
```

---

**New answer**

You subsequently showed the full input string. This makes my solution above obsolete. It turns out to be a complete XML document. In this case, I suggest extracting the information by using XML serialization. It is the easiest way to extract information from a complex XML string or file.

We need these usings:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Let's declare the following classes representing the data:

```cs
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class Response
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public int Smstat { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Sca { get; set; }
    public int SaveType { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public int SmsType { get; set; }
}
```

We can extract all the information from the XML with:

```cs
const string XmlString =
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<response>
    ...
</response>";

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response), new[] { typeof(Message) });
using var reader = new StringReader(XmlString);
var response = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

Console.WriteLine(
  $"Response count = {response.Count}, Messages count = {response.Messages.Count}");
var m = response.Messages[0];
Console.WriteLine(
  $"Index = {m.Index}, Phone = {m.Phone}, Content = {m.Content}, Date = {m.Date}");
```

Produces the following output:

> Response count = 2, Messages count = 2
> Index = 20001, Phone = +4857782, Content = Test4, Date = 11.12.2021 14:24:23

For this to work, I had to convert the date format in the XML to the standard XML date format `2021-12-11T14:24:23`, i.e, with a `T` between date and time instead of a space. If you don't want to do this, you can replace the `Date` property in the `Message` class by these two properties converting the custom date format:

```cs
[XmlIgnore]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

[XmlElement("Date")]
public string DateString
{
    get => Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    set => Date = DateTime.Parse(value);
}
```

Instead of deserializing from a string with a `StringReader`, you can also deserialize directly from a file with

```cs
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response), new[] { typeof(Message) });
using var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
var response = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```

---

**Summary**

You can read the detailed information form a complex XML with just three lines of code without having to deal with XML tags and string indexes by using [XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization).

Answer (score 0):

An answer using regular expression:

```
var mainString = "<Message>1</Message><Message>2</Message><Message>3</Message>";

string p  = "<[^>]*>([^<]*)<[^>]*>";
Regex r = new Regex(p);
foreach (Match item in r.Matches(mainString))
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Groups[1]);
}
            }
```

This will output:

```
1
2
3
```

The regular expression can be read as:

- `<[^>]*>`

-- find a `<`

-- followed by any character not being a `>` 0 or more times `[^>]*`

-- followed by a `>`

- `([^<]*)`

-- find any character, not a `<` 0 or more times

-- The `()` make it possible to reference this found piece.

- `<[^>]*>`

-- same as first part, to find the closing tag.

P.S. Explaining regular expressions is not my most popular subject ...

see also: [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/HfvLCz/1)

Comment: not sure if this gonna work, as it can be 10 messages or 3 or 0

Comment: For 0 matches you have to check the result of `r.Matches(mainString)`. it will be null if there is noting found.. More matches should work without problems.